# Change codec of WAV file

Tags: ffmpeg, wav, audio-conversion

Is there a way to change the codec/format of WAV file? Can I use `ffmpeg`or anything else?

From

```
RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 8 bit, mono 8000 Hz
```

to

```
RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, ITU G.711 u-law, mono 8000 Hz
```

UPDATE

```
root]# ffmpeg -codecs
FFmpeg version SVN-rUNKNOWN, Copyright (c) 2000-2007 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
configuration: --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-amr_nb
libavutil version: 49.3.0
libavcodec version: 51.38.0
libavformat version: 51.10.0
built on Dec  7 2007 16:31:16, gcc: 3.2.3 20030502 (Red Hat Linux 3.2.3-24)
ffmpeg: missing argument for option '-codecs'
```

UPDATE2: And here is what happen when I try

```
root]#ffmpeg -i 110.wav -c:a pcm_mulaw new.wav
FFmpeg version SVN-rUNKNOWN, Copyright (c) 2000-2007 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
configuration: --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-amr_nb
libavutil version: 49.3.0
libavcodec version: 51.38.0
libavformat version: 51.10.0
built on Dec  7 2007 16:31:16, gcc: 3.2.3 20030502 (Red Hat Linux 3.2.3-24)
Input #0, wav, from '110.wav':
Duration: 00:00:06.8, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 64 kb/s
Stream #0.0: Audio: pcm_u8, 8000 Hz, mono, 64 kb/s
ffmpeg: unrecognized option '-c:a'
```

Comment: Dude, why is your version of ffmpeg from 2007?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -c:a pcm_mulaw output.wav
```

Check `ffmpeg -codecs` for a list of supported codecs. An `E` in the listing means encoding support.

Comment: Hm.. it's seems that there is no codecs on the system. Please check my updated question.

Comment: Well, you're running a version from 2007 (that's seven years old!), so head to http://ffmpeg.org/download.html and download a new static build.

Comment: Yeah .. the linux distribution on this machine is also from the prehistoric but I can't 'refreshing' it at this time. I'll try to update `ffmpeg` at least and will let you know if it's work the conversion

Comment: Ok, I've tried ot virtual box under Ubuntu. The output file is `RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, ITU G.711 mu-law, mono 8000 Hz` which is good OK but is there a differents between `ITU G.711 mu-law` and `ITU G.711 u-law`? What is this `m` in `mu-law`?

Comment: Also I don't see codec just for `u-law` so is `mu-law` same as `u-law`?

Comment: The Greek `µ` is also written as "mu", and if you only have ASCII, then you'd use a `u`, so it's the same :)